# Nuxt Axios post to Laravel API with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, laravel-7

I'm using the nuxt axios module I'm trying to post it with an object but this doesn't work

```
async postOrder(data) {
try {
  await this.$axios.$post('orders', {
    form: data
    // other parameters..
  })

  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  });
  } catch(err) {
console.log(err);}
```

in laravel controller

```
        $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'address_1' => 'required',
        'address_2' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'postcode' => 'required',
        'country_id' => 'required|exists:countries,id',
    ]);

    $address = new Address;
    $address->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $address->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $address->address_1 = $request->address_1;
    $address->address_2 = $request->address_2;
    $address->city = $request->city;
    $address->postcode = $request->postcode;
    $address->country_id = $request->country_id;
    $address->save();
```

it works if I pass it in like this I'm guessing it's something to do with the fact I'm using form: data?

```
await this.$axios.$post('orders', this.form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can validate and post like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'form.first_name' => 'required',
        'form.last_name' => 'required',
        'form.address_1' => 'required',
        'form.address_2' => 'required',
        'form.city' => 'required',
        'form.postcode' => 'required',
        'form.country_id' => 'required|exists:countries,id',
    ]);

    $address = new Address;
    $address->first_name = $request['form.first_name'];
    $address->last_name = $request['form.last_name'];
    $address->address_1 = $request['form.address_1'];
    $address->address_2 = $request['form.address_2'];
    $address->city = $request['form.city'];
    $address->postcode = $request['form.postcode'];
    $address->country_id = $request['form.country_id'];
    $address->save();
```

but can also use the spread operator ...this.form and wouldn't need to access them like the above in the controller

```
enter async postOrder () {
  try {
     await this.$axios.$post('orders',{
      ...this.form,
      shipping_id: this.$store.state.shipping.id,
    })

  } catch (e) {

  }
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You are posting data wrapped in a `form` object, so you have to change your validation rules to:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'form.first_name' => 'required',
    'form.last_name' => 'required',
    etc...
```

You should also checkout your console to see the catched error exception from the try/catch in your Nuxt app.